# Сравнение одинаковых значение в БД

Tags: mysql, javascript, php, sql

Как реализовать такое:

Если в БД существует имя пользователя (например user), и при регистрации новый пользователь пытается записать такое же имя (user), как составить запрос, чтобы в таком случае было сообщение, типа "Извините, но пользователь с таким именем уже существует"
Вот например мой запрос:

```
if (!empty($_POST))
    {
        if (($_POST['url'] != "") and ($_POST['name'] != ""))
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO woo_pages (url,name,description,keywords,title,active) VALUES ('/".(trim($_POST['url']))."/','".(trim($_POST['name']))."','".(trim($_POST['description']))."','".(trim($_POST['keywords']))."','".(trim($_POST['title']))."','".(trim($_POST['active']))."')";                             
                if (mysql_query($sql));
                echo "success";
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select user from table where user = newuser
```

Если вернет ответ, значит имя занято

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь проверять существование такого пользователя именно на этапе записи в таблицу, тогда поставь уникальность на поле user, тогда при попытке вставить запись с таким user, вернется ошибка, которую тебе надо словить и в соответствии с ней сказать вернуть на страницу сообщение, что такое имя пользователя уже есть.

Но по правильному существование такого пользователя нужно проверять **также** и на уровне валидации введенных пользователем данных.